# How to sanitize user input?

Tags: plugin-development, forms, escaping, sanitization

What is the correct way sanitizing form data before submitting to the database? I have the following text input:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>

<input style="width:100%" type="text" name="data[title]" id="title" value="<?php $title = get_option('data_test'); echo $title['title']; ?>" /></p>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="lu_ban_data"/>
    <input style="float:left;margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; vertical-align: middle; clear: both;" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="<?php _e('save changes') ?>" />
</form>
```

I tried doing `echo sanitize_text_field($title['title']);`, but it only sanitizes the data upon requesting it from the db, the data inside the db still contains unwanted characters. This is why I want to sanitize before submitting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this helpful or not. As s_ha_dum said, you should post how you are processing the submitted data and sending to db.

But for starters, you might look at escaping the outputted data in the form:

```
<input style="width:100%" type="text" name="data[title]" id="title" value="<?php $title = get_option('data_test'); echo esc_attr($title['title']); ?>" /></p>
```

Use [esc_attr()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr) and [esc_html()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html) for data that you are adding to the page that has been submitted by the user or you are unsure of its origins.

`esc_attr()` is for content outputted into an html tag attribute, and `esc_html()` is for content outputted directly into the page or between tags. There are also `esc_attr_e()`, `esc_attr__()`, `esc_html_e`, and `esc_html__()` versions if you need translation.

Finally, within the escaping series is [esc_sql()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_sql) for user submitted data that you are going to send to your database.

**EDIT**:

As @Milo pointed out in the comments, there isn't much use for esc_sql() here, because those escape functions are getting applied already to update_option() through the sanitize_option() function and prepared when placed in the database. So you can skip that. If you are writing your own MySQL calls to store data, you should look at $wpdb->prepare to escape them.

For adding meta_data and options to the database through built in functions, you are already covered.

Comment: If you're inserting data directly in the db (raw SQL), `$wpdb`'s `prepare` is preferred over `esc_sql()`. If you're using the API to insert data (your `update_option` example), WordPress is already using prepared queries so escaping that data is redundant.

Comment: Hmmm. Good point. I was trying to come up with a use for esc_sql, and now I can't.